# Selling ETFs in Roth IRA fund, in exchange to buy Bonds tax implications

Tags: taxes, stocks, roth-ira, bonds, capital-gains-tax

I would like to sell ETFs in my Roth IRA fund, in exchange to buy Bonds. 
What are the tax implications of this?

Even if the money is still held in the Roth IRA fund, would I get taxed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can sell any investment within an IRA/Roth IRA/401K/529 and not have to pay capital gains tax, as long as the money stays within the IRA/Roth IRA/401K/529. You can then purchase another investment as long as it also stays in the IRA/Roth IRA/401K/529.

If your provider doesn't have the investment you want, then you will have to roll over the funds into another IRA/Roth IRA/401K/529 to make the new purchase.

Depending on the exact type of retirement fund your capital gains may be tax deferred or tax exempt.